# Veracrypt error on hidden volume

Tags: linux, mount, truecrypt, veracrypt

Accidental I downloaded some files on the normal volume of veracrypt and now my hidden volume won't mount. I get this type of error

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/veracrypt,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Files that I downloaded I've already deleted.

Is there are way to fix my Hidden volume now ?

Answer (score 0):

Not easily (but it's not impossible to get back some data, depending on the underlying filesystem and how much of the hidden partition you overwrote).

It seems like you have managed to corrupt the start of the hidden volume, do you have most likely overwritten some key data.

The error seems to imply you have decrypted the hidden volume ok but the fact is stuffed.

THE FIRST THING YOU SHOULD DO IS A BITCOPY OF THE AFFRCTED DRIVE, as recovery attempts can make things worse.  Once you have done the steps to recovery are to find the name of the decrypted block device and apply standard data recovery techniques on it. (DdRescue is one possible tool)

(I've not done it but) you may be able to find the name of the block device by looking at /var/log/syslog, dmesg or kern.log.  Alternatively by sorting through /dev/disk and /dev/mapper

Once you have identified the unencrypted hidden block device, try using  testdisk. If the partition type is EXT, you may be be able to search for an alternative super block (https://www.quora.com/What-are-all-the-things-one-can-try-to-recover-an-ext3-filesystem-with-a-bad-superblock) - worst case run photorec to seewhat it can recover from the raw disk)